# Async Pipe not updating View when observable changes

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscription, behaviorsubject

I have a global service that saves a behaviour subject. The Behaviour subject stores an array. I have a filter component which emits a new version of that array, which I can see changes on the global service. However, where the behaviour subject is being used as async pipe, the values in the view do not change.

Here is my approach:

In my global service, I have a Behaviour Subject

`public dataArray$: BehaviorSubject<Data[]> = new BehaviorSubject(someData);`

filter component extends the Global service as so:

`export class FilterComponent extends GlobalDataService`

and then a triggerFilter function alters the original data (as a base point for the filter) and provides a new value to emit for the Behaviour Subject:

`public triggerFilter(option: string): void {...`

inside the function as so:

`const filteredData = someData.filter(item => item.array.includes(option));`
`this.dataArray$.next(filteredData);`

when subscribing inside the global data service as so:

`constructor() { this.showcase$.subscribe((res) => console.log('service', res))}`

I can see the .next method is being called and printing out the new array. But the async pipe anywhere it is being used is not emitting the new values to the view - thus the filter isn't working...

```
<app-filter></app-filter>
<app-data-items></app-data-items>
```

inside app-data-items:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="dataArray$ | async as dataArray">
     <span *ngFor="let data of dataArray" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + data.background + ')' }">
         <app-data-details [data]="data"></app-data-details>
     </span>
</ng-container>
```

This view doesn't update when the values from the behaviour subject change. My assumption would be that the async pipe once defined on view will automatically open a subscription and alter the values once changed? This is the point of the async pipe if I'm not correct?

I'm using Angular 16 and am currently scratching my head as to why this isn't working. I've considered triggering some form of change detection strategy (cdRef etc), but this seems like an anti measure when using async? This should be handled via the async pipe?

Anyone had this issue before and could offer some guidance?

Comment: Please provide a full code example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: fixed it. Seems like using class extension was the issue. Using the service as a dependency in the constructor, updates the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your component is extending the `GlobalDataService`, thus creating a local *copy* of it. In this way its `dataArray$` value will be different wrom the one in the service, because they are two different objects.
If you want to share information across components, you should use your service as a [`Singleton`](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services).

In an nutshell, you only update and read `dataArray$` from the `GlobalDataService` in all your components, and inject the same instance of `GlobalDataService` in all your interested components.

**`GlobalDataService`**

```
export class GlobalDataService {
    public dataArray$: BehaviorSubject<Data[]> = new BehaviorSubject(someData);

    public filterData(option: string): void {
        const filteredData = doStuffWithOptions(options);
        this.dataArray$.next(filteredData);
    }}
```

**`FilterComponent`**

```
export class FilterComponent {
    triggerFilter(option: string): void {
        // You modify the BehaviourSubject in the service
        this.publicDataService.filterData(option)
    }
}
```

**`DataItemsComponent`**

```
export class DataItemsComponent  {
    // Here you are doing a shallow copy of the BehaviourSubject
    public dataArray$ = this.publicDataService.dataArray$
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="dataArray$ | async as dataArray">
     <span *ngFor="let data of dataArray" [ngStyle]="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + data.background + ')' }">
         <app-data-details [data]="data"></app-data-details>
     </span>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I've found and altered it pretty much like the above. I'll give it the tick, as this will help people moving forward. Many thanks.